# A sinusoidal trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I need to plot a graph of the following function for values time, $0\le t\le2\pi$ (radians).

$$y=5\sin\left(2t + \frac\pi6\right)$$

I need to describe and define the amplitude, periodic time and frequency.

Can the formula be put into Excel somehow to plot the graph?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the definitions of what you are looking for?

Comment: The free GeoGebra program is easier. Download it and in the input line at the bottom type your formula with x instead of t and type $\pi$ as pi.

Comment: Or graph it on-line at https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Answer (score 1):

Well if *finding* the amplitude, periodic time, and frequency is all you have to do, it's very simple. For any curve $asin(bx + c)$, the amplitude is $a$, the period is $\dfrac{2\pi}{b}$ and the frequency is $\dfrac{b}{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

Enter the initial value of $t$ in a cell. In the right neighbor, enter the formula `=5*SIN(2*?+PI()/6)` where the question mark replaces a click in the left cell.

In the cell below the initial value, enter the initial value plus the desired step. Select both cells and extend downward to the desired final value.

Select the cell with the formula and extend downward. You should then have two columns with pairs $(t, f(t))$.

Select the two columns and insert a scatter plot.

[image]